# Add required validation to all controls of reactive FormGroup if at least one field has value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a form group which has few controls, all fields are required only if at least one field has value. i.e. Either user can keep all fields blank or enter data in all fields. And each control needs to be validated to display the required error below it.

I tried building custom validator for that with the help of inbuilt required validator but it is validating current control only.

```
allFieldRequired(ctrlName: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (ctrl: AbstractControl) => {
      if (!ctrl.parent || !Object.values(ctrl.parent.value).join('')) {
        return null;
      }
      return CustomValidators.required()(ctrl)
    }
  }
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-validation) is my implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply

```
this.myForm.get('myFirstControl').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  for (const control of this.myForm.controls) {
    if (!value) { control.setValidators([]); }
    else { control.setValidators([Validators.required]); }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it correct This way I need to subscribe to from valueChanges if I want to check form value the question is about all form controls 

Comment: You can subscribe to form value changes instead of control value changes, That's the same thing : I just thought you had a single input to listen to. If it is all, simply test that `value === {}`

Comment: but the valueChanges will emit a value every time any form control value changes so we need to prevent multiple loop (rxjs map => true/false , distinctUntilChanged ) and another problem is remove others validators  when I want to remove Validators.required => control.setValidators([])

Comment: There's no multiple loop, you don't update the value but the validators. And you answered your own question yourself on the second point.

Comment: sorry I mean with the multiple loop is the for/of but this can be handled with rxjs but remove the required validator will remove others validator right I don't find a way to remove only the required validator =>  my problem is the setValidators([])

Comment: Yes it will remove other validators. You should store them somewhere like `validators = { name: [Validators.maxLength(24)], age: [Validators.min(0)] }` and use `control.setValidators([...this.validators.name])`

Comment: @trichetriche, Thanks for the solution but it is just validating based on the field which is going to change. but it is not validating pristine controls. Here is the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-validation

Comment: Indeed, then you should consider using @malbarmawi's answer !

Answer (score 2):

this consider a different way but you can add required validator dynamically based on condtion like this

```
 <input type="text" formControlName="user" [required]="hasValue()">
```

component

```
  hasValue(){
    return Object.values(this.form.value).join('').trim().length > 0
  }
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53646495)

Comment: Great idea, `[required]="form.value !== {}"` would be the condition !

Comment: `form.value !== {}` will not work becuase value is an `object` so I need to check each property value `join('').trim().length` this a trick  to get values as array join the array values as string this just an indecator of any value 

Comment: Right, but at least you get the idea :D